# Protractor promise return string to compare with value

Tags: javascript, jasmine, promise, protractor, e2e-testing

i am using protractor to test AngularJS website. I need some protractor function to return a value of promise to continue in my code right way.

Especially, i need to get value from input and compare it with some constant. Tried this way:

```
    var p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        if (element(by.id('policyNumber')).getAttribute('value') == parameter.getJinyDotazParams().attributes.policyNumber) {
            resolve("Success");
        } else {
            reject("Error");
        }
    });

    p1.then(function (value) {
        console.log(value + 'yaaay'); // Success!
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log(reason + 'Q_Q'); // Error!
    });
```

For example, with boolean return everything work:

```
    var p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        if (element(by.id('policyNumber')).isDisplayed()) {
            resolve("Success");
        } else {
            reject("Error");
        }

        //resolve("Success!");
        // or
        //reject("Error!");
    });

    p1.then(function (value) {
        console.log(value + 'yaaay'); // Success!
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log(reason + 'Q_Q'); // Error!
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did not expect, that would be so easy..

```
element(by.id('policyNumber')).getAttribute('value').then(function (val) {
    if (val == parameter.getJinyDotazParams().attributes.policyNumber) {
        console.log('YAAAAY!');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Jasmine framework then you can use expect() method to validate the output of a promise. For example,

```
var displayedValue =element(by.id('policyNumber')).getAttribute('value')
var actualValue = parameter.getJinyDotazParams().attributes.policyNumber
expect(displayedValue).toEqual(actualValue)
```

Comment: Sure, but i wanted to continu in my code continue value from the input.